# Please make WPSE keyboard accessible

Tags: feature-request

I cannot reach the comment tools without a mouse. Why? The only way to make those visible is on `:hover`. Since I had to fight all the day with WordPress’ broken new menus I don’t want to use a mouse (my fingers hurt, I cannot stretch them anymore).

[image]

So, my request is: Make it better than the UI agnostic guys from WP. Make WPSE accessible. :)

Comment: Is this specific to WPSE, or to all SE sites? If this pertains to all SE sites, I suggest searching and then asking on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @tnorthcutt It’s not specific to WPSE. But we were told once to ask meta question here first.

Answer (score 2):

There was a post on official blog today [Stack Exchange Keyboard Shortcuts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-keyboard-shortcuts/) that says while keyboard shortcuts are not integrated yet, there is [Official keyboard shortcuts](https://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts) user script available right now and until it's implemented in site itself.

Comment: I use Opera – many of these shortcuts are already taken in my browser or they just don’t work. In my example it is impossible to vote on a comment. Shortcuts don’t help here.

Comment: @toscho Opera is far less than 1% of all usage on our network, so unfortunately conflicts that are specific to Opera are not a priority. Now if it conficted on IE, Firefox, Chrome, or even in some cases Safari..

Comment: @JeffAtwood Keyboard accessibility is bad in _all_ browsers: No or almost invisible focus styles, hidden elements which are accessible to mouse users only … Opera can handle the network sites actually _better_ than Firefox or IE because it offers usable focus styles and spatial navigation. But it is still not good enough and rather frustrating.